# iPhone 6 Plus Resolution Image for custom keyboard in iOS8

Tags: image, ios8, resolution, iphone-6-plus

I am confusing about the resolution of image that will use for `iPhone 6 Plus`.

My App is Keyboard Extension for Custom Keyboard.

I use Background Image for Keyboard.

For iPhone 5 , 5s , background image pixel size is

```
320px x 216px

640px x 432px for @2x
```

But for iPhone 6 Plus , i use @3x Resolution.So

```
960px x 648px
```

It's because i multiply `320 x 3 = 960`

However when i test in iPhone 6 Plus Simulator , Keyboard Background Image is a little blurring and not perfectly.

[image]

I am sure that my pics is not blurring.

Is my Calculation for `@3x` right? or something wrong?

Comment: "Keyboard Background Image is a little blurring" can you show the picture?

Comment: Did you put any check to show image for iPhone 6 plus?

Comment: @Jonast92 Added Image And Hemant No.

Comment: I think it's best if you take a screenshot of the default keyboard from the iPhone 6 Plus simulator at 100% scale (command-1 in the Simulator or Window > Scale > 100%), and use that to check the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found solution for my own question.It's because of Apple's `Scale Mode Feature` that allow app can run in `iPhone 6` and `iPhone 6+` with normal resolution.

My solution is When i add `iCon` and Launch screen image for `iPhone 6` and `iPhone 6+` , the full HD Retina Display can display.

iCon Size are :

```
1. 87 x 87
2. 120 x 120
3. 180 x 180
```

For `iPhone 6+` Landscape Launch screen image size is : `2208 × 1242`

For `iPhone 6+` Portrait Launch screen image size is : `1242 × 2208`

For `iPhone 6` Portrait Launch screen image size is : `750 × 1334`

After added above iCons and Launch screen images , my app working with full resolution.